# Custom Concatenate in C

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to write my own concatenate program. What I'm doing is getting two strings as input from `argv`, creating a third empty character array that holds the length of `argv[1] + argv[2]`, and then use two `for` loops to insert the characters from each `argv` string into the third string.

My first `for` loop seems to be working fine buy my second for `loop` isn't doing anything. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *string1 = argv[1];
  char *string2 = argv[2];

  int string1Len = strnlen(string1, 50);
  int string2Len = strnlen(string2, 50);

  char string3[string1Len + string2Len + 1];

  for (int i = 0; i <= string1Len; i++)
  {
    string3[i] = string1[i];
  }

  for(int i = (string1Len + 1); i <= (string1Len + string2Len); i++)
  {
    string3[i] = string2[i];
  }

  string3[string1Len + string2Len + 1] = '\0';

  printf("%s %d %d\n", string3, string1Len, string2Len);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How much is `i` in the second loop? and does it agree with `string2`?

Comment: user344658, Why the magic number 50 instead of `string1Len = strlen(string1);?` Are you  distrusting the parameters from `main()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify (and optimize) it by using the `memcpy` function

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 3) return 1;
    const char *string1 = argv[0];
    const char *string2 = argv[1];
    const size_t string1Len = strlen(string1);
    const size_t string2Len = strlen(string2);
    char *string3 = malloc((string1Len + string2Len + 1) * sizeof(*string3));
    memcpy(string3, string1, string1Len * sizeof(*string1));
    memcpy(string3 + string1Len, string2, (string2Len + 1) * sizeof(*string2));

    printf("%s %zu %zu", string3, string1Len, string2Len);
    free(string3);
    return 0;
}
```

And as the others said, pay attention to the nul terminator

Comment: Almost great.  1) use matching print specifier: `"%zu"` for `size_t` and not `"%d"`.  2) size to the referenced object, not type:  `* sizeof(char)` --> `* sizeof *string3` 3) pedantic code would detect `string1Len + string2Len + 1` overflow.

Comment: Edited according to points 1 and 2.
However, I do not see what could be the problem with the third point. `strlen()` returns the size of the string, excluding the final `\0`, so we need to add a last byte in our malloc in order to contain the `\0` we will add at the end of string3. Then, in the second `memcpy`, we copy the string2Len bytes at the address of *string2, plus one byte : the null terminator.

Comment: imperosol, with _extremely_ long strings, the sum of their two lengths could exceed `SIZE_MAX`.  Not a common concern.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I didn't considered this case.

Comment: Not really worth checking as it is so extreme, But `if (string1Len  >= SIZE_MAX - string2Len) TooLong()` is such a check.

Answer (score 0):

Your second for loop "did nothing" because the first one worked up to the `\0` character and included it in `string3`, so it's better to set the condition that the for loop works up to that character

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *string1 = argv[1];
  char *string2 = argv[2];

  int string1Len = strlen(string1);
  int string2Len = strlen(string2);

  int i;

  char string3[string1Len + string2Len +1];

  for (i = 0; string1[i]!='\0'; i++)
  {
    string3[i] = string1[i];
  }
  string3[i]=' ';   //with space
  ++i;
  for(int j = 0; string2[j]!='\0'; j++)
  {
    string3[i] = string2[j];
    i++;
  }

  string3[string1Len + string2Len + 1] = '\0';

  printf("%s %d %d\n", string3, string1Len, string2Len);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues in your code. Your first `for` loop copies the `nul` terminator from `string1`; so, anything you then add to your `string3` *after* that will simply be ignored by functions like `printf`, because they see that `nul` as marking the end of the string.

In your second `for` loop, you have the same problem and, more critically, the `i` index you use is not valid for `string2`, as you have added the length of `string1` to it.

Also, note that arrays in C start at zero, so you shouldn't add the 1 to the position of the final `nul` terminator.

Here's the "quick fix" for your current code:

```c
    for (int i = 0; i < string1Len; i++) { // Use "<" in place of "<=" or we copy the null terminator
        string3[i] = string1[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < string2Len; i++) { // Start "i" at 0 for valid "string2" index ...
        string3[i + string1Len] = string2[i]; // ... and add "string1Len" for the destination index
    }
    string3[string1Len + string2Len] = '\0'; // Arrays start at ZERO, so don't add 1 for "nul" terminator position
```

However, there are some other points and possible improvements. Note that the `strnlen` function returns a `size_t` type, so you would be better off using that for your indexes. Also, as you know that the `i` index at the end of the first loop will still be valid for the next character, you can re-use that in the second loop (so long as you have declared it outside the first loop), and you can use a second index for the source string.

Also, [as pointed out by chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69865175/10871073), you really should check that you have sufficient source data in the `argv` array.

Here's a version of your program with those additional changes:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        // Error-handling code
        return 1;
    }
    char* string1 = argv[1];
    char* string2 = argv[2];
    size_t string1Len = strnlen(string1, 50);
    size_t string2Len = strnlen(string2, 50);
    size_t i, j;
    char string3[string1Len + string2Len + 1];

    for (i = 0; i < string1Len; i++) {
        string3[i] = string1[i];
    }
    for (j = 0; j < string2Len; j++, i++) {
        string3[i] = string2[j];
    }
    string3[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s %zu %zu\n", string3, string1Len, string2Len); // "%zu" for "size_t"
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The index values in both loops are incorrect:

- you should stop the first loop when `i == string1Len`, hence the test should be:

  ```
   for (int i = 0; i < string1Len; i++)
  ```
- you should use add `string1Len` to the index into the destination string so bytes from the second string are appended to those of the first string:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < string2Len; i++) {
      string3[string1Len + i] = string2[i];
  }
  ```
- the index for the null terminator is `string1Len + string2Len`, adding `1` is incorrect as indexing is zero based in C:

  ```
   string3[string1Len + string2Len] = '\0';
  ```
- you should test the actual number of arguments provided to the program to avoid undefined behavior if some are missing.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *string1 = argv[1];
    char *string2 = argv[2];

    int string1Len = strnlen(string1, 50);
    int string2Len = strnlen(string2, 50);

    char string3[string1Len + string2Len + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < string1Len; i++) {
        string3[i] = string1[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < string2Len; i++) {
        string3[string1Len + i] = string2[i];
    }

    string3[string1Len + string2Len] = '\0';

    printf("%s %d %d\n", string3, string1Len, string2Len);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your second loop is that `i` starts beyond the beginning of the second string. However, if all you are trying to do is to write you own *custom* (max 50 chars) concatenate program, all you need to do is to `printf` the arguments one after the other and `printf` can help limit:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) printf("%.50s", argv[i]);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

There is no need to copy in memory to a VLA and print.

If you need to create a function that concatenates, you better use `malloc` - as you can't safely return a VLA: (note, the following example will not limit to 50 chars):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* concat(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  size_t totalsize = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) totalsize += strlen(argv[i]);

  char* ret = malloc(totalsize);
  if (!ret) exit(1);
  if (!argc) *ret = 0;

  char* dst = ret;
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
    char* src = argv[i];
    while (*dst++ = *src++); /* Copy also the \0 */
    --dst;
  }
  return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char* str = concat(argc - 1, argv + 1); /* Skip the program name */
  printf("%s\n", str);
  free(str);
  return 0;
}
```

Note that the above examples will concatenate any number of strings.